# Parsing error using net.sf.tweety.lp.asp.solver.Clingo

Tags: java, clingo

I am trying to run the clingo solver from net.sf.tweety.lp.asp, version 1.8. 
I am using clingo version 4.3.0.

The code is:

```
Clingo solver = new Clingo("/homes/ftm13/bin/clingo");
solver.computeModels(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("/homes/ftm13/project/examples/remove_ec_example.lp")),1);
```

When I run it I get the following error:

clingo: error parsing answer set!
net.sf.tweety.lp.asp.parser.ParseException: Encountered "  "version "" at line 1, column 9.
Was expecting one of:
    "," ...
    "(" ...
    "}" ...

```
at net.sf.tweety.lp.asp.parser.ASPParser.generateParseException(ASPParser.java:1918)
at net.sf.tweety.lp.asp.parser.ASPParser.jj_consume_token(ASPParser.java:1800)
at net.sf.tweety.lp.asp.parser.ASPParser.AnswerSet(ASPParser.java:177)
at net.sf.tweety.lp.asp.parser.ASPParser.AnswerSetList(ASPParser.java:120)
at net.sf.tweety.lp.asp.solver.Clingo.parseAnswerSets(Clingo.java:46)
at net.sf.tweety.lp.asp.solver.Clingo.buildASL(Clingo.java:132)
at net.sf.tweety.lp.asp.solver.Clingo.computeModels(Clingo.java:78)
```

Any ideas regarding what might be causing it?

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the source you are parsing. What does it contain?

Comment: Apparently the clingo version I am using is not currently supported...